# I am in need of this error rectification in tableau.When I try to connect tableau with my data , say for example , a excel sheet,I get an error

Tags: error-handling, operating-system, tableau-desktop, tableau-cloud

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QLowm.png)
if you still want the whole error message I can give it to you
The characters in the error log is exceeding more than 600000
The sample file or the error image is given above
I tried to even change the permissions and security but there is no change in it

Comment: Can you clarify what is happening, an excel sheet is a very different connection than say a database. But this looks a like a permission issue. Please be specific when asking questions, we do not know what you have tried.